# Is it possible to apply a hover element in jQuery to two divs with show and hide functionality?

Tags: jquery, html, hover, hide, show

There is some flickering when I use the show and hide functionality on my divs.
I'm using the following code now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tekstvanitem-1").hide();
  $("#thumbnail-1").hover(function(){
   $("#tekstvanitem-1").show();
   },function(){
   $("#tekstvanitem-1").hide();


 });
});
```

The problem is when i rollover thumbnail-1 it show tekstvanitem-1. But because tekstvanitem-1 pops up over thumbnail-1 it then looks like its flickering because im not on thumbnail-1 anymore. So it's kind of a loop.

Is it possible to set the hover element when either my mouse is on thumbnail-1 or if my mouse is on tekstvanitem-1?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqhqz/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.  Just put `#tekstvanitem-1` in the selector...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tekstvanitem-1").hide();
    $("#thumbnail-1, #tekstvanitem-1").hover(function(){
        $("#tekstvanitem-1").show();
    },function(){
        $("#tekstvanitem-1").hide();
    });
});
```